# Get single object from Kotlin list of objects

Tags: android, json, kotlin, collections

I have a JsonArray that contains a list of animal and is as followed

```
"animalList": [
                {
                    "species": "Owl",
                    "name": "Kludd",
                    "status": "Dead",
                    "diet": "Carnivores",
                    "weight": "1.4 lbs"
                },
                {
                    "species": "Tiger",
                    "name": "Aslan",
                    "status": "Alive",
                    "diet": "Carnivores",
                    "weight": "295 lbs"
                },
                {
                    "species": "Bear",
                    "name": "Kenai",
                    "status": "Alive.",
                    "diet": "Omnivore",
                    "weight": "330 lbs"
                },
                {
                    "species": "Human",
                    "name": "Peter",
                    "status": "Alive",
                    "diet": "Omnivores",
                    "weight": "150 lbs"
                }
            ]
```

I've pull this into the project as a List? and now I'm having trouble accessing and printing only one object and it's information. Is there a way to check what species it is and only print it out if it's the species I'm checking for?

Comment: create a class for each of these (probably a class called animal or something similar, something which fits all these values), parse this data into that model, then check the `species` value

Answer (score 0):

First of all, the json has a problem according to this [Json Format Validator](https://jsonformatter.curiousconcept.com/#) and should be like this (remove the animalList):

```json
[
   {
      "species":"Owl",
      "name":"Kludd",
      "status":"Dead",
      "diet":"Carnivores",
      "weight":"1.4 lbs"
   },
   {
      "species":"Tiger",
      "name":"Aslan",
      "status":"Alive",
      "diet":"Carnivores",
      "weight":"295 lbs"
   },
   {
      "species":"Bear",
      "name":"Kenai",
      "status":"Alive.",
      "diet":"Omnivore",
      "weight":"330 lbs"
   },
   {
      "species":"Human",
      "name":"Peter",
      "status":"Alive",
      "diet":"Omnivores",
      "weight":"150 lbs"
   }
]
```

You should also create a class for them as shown below:

```kotlin
data class Animal (
    val species: String,
    val name: String,
    val status: String,
    val diet: String,
    val weight: String
)
```

Now with a List you can get a certain animal by checking it's status as shown below:

```kotlin
val animalList = ArrayList<Animal>()
animalList.forEach { animal ->
 if (animal.status == "Tiger") {
// do something   
 }
}
```